# Faster to slower port speed

Tags: switch, speed

I have a network switch that supports up to and including 1000 Mbps. If I have a `Client A` with 100 Mbps and `Client B` with 1000 Mbps connection, will:

1. the connection between `A`and `B` be limited to 100 Mbps, therefore the data sent is not buffered? Since each port negotiates with the selected/default speed, `A` would default to 100 Mbps and `B` would default to 1000 Mbps.
2. the data sent be buffered? If this is the case, where is the buffer stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traffic between the two hosts will be limited to the speed of the slowest link.

Switches have a *very small* amount of buffering for situations like this. If the host with the faster link tries to stream a lot of data to the host with the slower link, many frames will be discarded, and ethernet has no facility for retransmission. You would depend on the upper-layer protocols (TCP or the application) to retransmit lost data.

Some hosts and switches support [ethernet flow control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_flow_control), but implementation and support of this can be very spotty.

Comment: When 1Gbps host -> 100Mbps host: Output queue (buffer) on switch will be utilized first to absorb oversubscription.  Once full, frames will be dropped as Ron says.  The buffer is tiny and fast - on-chip silicon - and is located in the switch itself.